# checkbox output in javascript query

Tags: javascript, checkbox, sparql, sgvizler

We have a few checkboxes of which we want to use the output in a javascript query. We have a few questions about sports and with every question people can check one checkbox, so that these outputs will be sent to the query. The query we have so far is the following:

```
<script>
    var Q = new sgvizler.Query(); 

    Q.query("SELECT ?sport WHERE { 
        ?sport o:IndividualOrTeam o:Team .
    }      

       .endpointURL("http://localhost/query")

       .endpointOutputFormat("json")                      

       .chartFunction("google.visualization.Table")      
       .draw("myElementID");                              
</script>
```

Now, what we want is that we can use the output of the checkboxes, which are variables, in our query as input. This would be as follows:

```
Q.query("SELECT ?sport WHERE { ?sport o:IndividualOrTeam o:[CheckboxOutput1] .
```

We already used code to check whether a checkbox is checked:

```
document.getElementById('team').checked;
```

for all checkboxes, we did the above. 
We know we can make a var query out of it, but do not know how we can get the variables into this query. I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can give your checkbox a value:

```js
var teamValue;
var team = document.getElementById('team');
if (team.checked)
{
  teamValue = team.value;
}
else
{
  teamValue = "individual";
}

console.log(teamValue)
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="team" type="checkbox" value="team" checked />team
</div>
```

After that you can concat the value:

```
sport o:IndividualOrTeam o:"+teamValue+"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [expression interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation).

```js
$("#test").click(function() {
  var Q = new sgvizler.Query();

  Q.query(`SELECT ?sport WHERE { ?sport o:IndividualOrTeam o:${document.getElementById('team').checked ? 'team' : 'individual'} }`);

  alert(Q.query());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://mgskjaeveland.github.io/sgvizler/v/0.6/sgvizler.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="team" />

<button id="test">Try Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost works. But how can we change the value so that it doesn't give true or false but for example Team or Individual? We tried adding a value within the input type checkbox part, but that still gave us true/false.

Comment: Edited the post. By using an inline if statement I converted the boolean value into a string.